# What are getResponse, getRequest functions? (Bonus: explanation of getUrl)

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I don't understand getResponse and getRequest functions of the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class.

EDIT:

See below an explanation of getUrl function!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRequest()` & `getResponse()` are basic functions that returns the Request & Response models for the current instance of page load.

More Clarification on **`getRequest()`** - Basically whenever you invoke a page via Controllers Action, you may pass some data as a Request(eg: Form data to save, Record Id to fetch information etc). This is nothing but request params to server for performing certain action. These all requested information goes within a Request Model. In controller action you can get these params as

`$this->getRequest()->getParam();`

More Clarification on **`getResponse()`** - Basically whenever you invoke a page via Controllers Action, you may expect some sort of response(eg: HTML content of page, JSON response format etc). This is nothing but response from server on calling a action. These all response information goes within a Response Model. In controller action you can set/update response as

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true)->setBody(json_encode($result));
```

**Add-On Bonus Knowledge: ;)**

More Clarification on **`getUrl()`** - `Mage::getUrl()` returns the Base Url of the website. You can pass params to get specific Url for any module, controller & action. Eg: You wanna get URL for Registration page, so you will call as `Mage::getUrl("customer/account/create")`. This will return full Url to Registration page. Pattern is `<module>/<controller>/<action>`.

You can pass `*` in case you wanna use current entity like module,controller or action. `*` will get replaced with current path. Eg: Consider you are now in ***customer/account/login*** action. Following will be output for `getUrl()` from this action.

```
Mage::getUrl()             -- <Base_Url>
Mage::getUrl("*")          -- <Base_Url>/customer/
Mage::getUrl("*/*")        -- <Base_Url>/customer/account/
Mage::getUrl("*/*/*")      -- <Base_Url>/customer/account/login/
Mage::getUrl("*/*/create") -- <Base_Url>/customer/account/create/
```

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: oh nice thanks ! I don't understand another function.. getUrl('\*/\*') what is the meaning of this parameter ?? –

Comment: @TheoCerutti I have updated my answer for getUrl(). Please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

getRequest: **this function used for get request parameter suppose if you are submitting a form and u want to get those submitted data then u have to use getRequest method for same**.

getResponse : **by using this function you redirect to any page etc.**